# Loading header file depending on the session in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, wordpress-theming

I'm designing and developing some blog on Wordpress, and I'm creating dedicated template.

My goal is to load different header for new session (let's say it is some kind of splashscreen) and different (normal) for every next request from the same machine (untill session downs).

For example: I have two PHP files: header-init.php and header.php and I want to make if statement with this two files.

How can I achieve that? Can I use WordPress build in session or am I need someting else?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you facing a specific programming problem? As far as i can see this question's scope is way to broad.

Comment: Actually answer below probably solve my problem, but i can't check it now. In my opinion it is really specyfic problem - how to load file depends on session in WordPress? Is there a wide spectrum of solutions? In my opinion not really.

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** : set session  function.php

```
add_action('init', 'letsstartsession', 1);
function letsstartsession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

**Step 2** : check session in your page.php post.php etc,

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['header_session'])){
    $get_val = $_SESSION['header_session'];
if($get_val =='header_value1'){get_header('header1');}    
else{
    get_header('header_default');
}
}else{
    get_header('header_default');
}
```